# Fortran: procedure pointer to method

Tags: oop, fortran, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I'm in the following situation: I have an object that must be initialized (without hurry) with some input parameter `x`. Then it has a method `do_work` that has to run (fast). Now, depending on `x` the `do_work` can be either function `f1` or `f2`. Of course I can choose among them when `do_work` is called, but, since I know the choice in advance, I was thinking to use a procedure pointer.

I produced the following MWE

```
module delegate_m
    implicit none

    private 

    type delegate
        private

        integer :: x
        procedure(delegate_function), private, pointer :: fptr
    contains
        private

        procedure:: f2
        procedure :: f1
        procedure, public :: do_work
    end type delegate

    interface delegate
        module procedure :: init_delegate
    end interface delegate

    abstract interface
        integer function delegate_function(self,y)
            import :: delegate
            class(delegate) :: self
            integer :: y
        end function delegate_function
    end interface

    public :: delegate

    contains
        type(delegate) function init_delegate(x)
            implicit none

            integer, intent(in) :: x

            init_delegate%x = x
            
            if (modulo(x, 2) == 0) then
                init_delegate%fptr => f1
            else
                init_delegate%fptr => f2
            end if 
        end function init_delegate

        integer function f1(self,y)
            implicit none

            class(delegate) :: self
            integer :: y

            f1 = y * self%x
        end function f1

        integer function f2(self,y)
            implicit none

            class(delegate) :: self
            integer :: y

            f2 = (y ** 2) * self%x
        end function f2

        integer function do_work(self, x, y)
            implicit none
        
            class(delegate) :: self
            integer:: x, y

            do_work = self%fptr(x) - y
        end function do_work
end module delegate_m

program test
    use delegate_m
    implicit none

    type(delegate) :: d1, d2
    d1 = delegate(45)
    d2 = delegate(44)

    write (*,*) d1%do_work(2, 3)
    write (*,*) d2%do_work(2, 3)
end program test
```

It seems to work, but I'm rather new to (modern) Fortran and I would like to know whether I did something wrong/dangerous since I'm working with pointers. I'm also curios if that `abstract interface` introduces some virtual function table lookup (I do not see why it should, but I'm a newbie, as I said)

Comment: pointers can generally be avoided in Fortran. But if you use them, remember to nullify them when the object goes out of scope. You could do so, for example, in the `final` procedure of your object (the object destructor).

Comment: Why do you have the bindings `f1` and `f2` in the derived type? They aren't used in this example , so perhaps you misunderstand or the code isn't as minimal as it could be.

Comment: I have `f1` and `f2` since the function pointer points to one of them. The function pointer is set at initialization time of the object, which does not have time constraint. This pattern is usually called delegate, as the name suggests.

Comment: I'm asking about the type bound procedures `f1` and `f2` (`procedure:: f2` etc.) which are not used, not the functions `f1` and `f2` which are used.

Comment: I see, you mean I could have put simply in the module. Is it correct?

Comment: If you want the type-bound procedures to use them in some other way, you may. They aren't used in this example, and they can never be used as "pointer targets". This last point is a common misunderstanding/error, and is why I wonder whether you think they are actually being used here (especially in light of the question title).

Comment: Sorry, I do not think what you mean when you say "they can never be used as "pointer target"". When I call `do_work` are `f1` a and `f2` called?. Could you provide an error free example of what I tried to achieve, since I think you understand my purpose?

Comment: The `f1` and `f2` that are the procedure targets are the functions `f1` and `f2` in the module, not the binding names `f1` and `f2` of the derived type. If you remove the lines `procedure :: f1` and `procedure :: f2` the example works in exactly the same way as it does now. If you know that type-bound procedures ("methods") are not involved in any way in this process, then you can ignore my comments.

Comment: To re-phrase @francescalus' comments: if you replaced the line `procedure :: f1` with `procedure :: f1 => f1_` and renamed the function `f1` to `f1_`, then the pointer association would be `init_delegate%fptr => f1_`, not `init_delegate%fptr => f1`. This doesn't change much in practice, as calling `foo%fptr(args)` will call `f1_(foo,args)`, and calling `foo%f1(args)` will also call `f1_(foo,args)` so the two are equivalent.

Comment: @King I must be missing something: Why do you think the pointers should be nullified before they go out of scope? They don't have target memory that needs deallocating, and the memory where the pointers themselves are stored will be overwritten along with the rest of the class.

Comment: Shouldn't I replace `class(delegate)` with `type(delegate)` as well?

Comment: I assume you mean in `f1_`? If you replaced `class(delegate)` with `type(delegate)` then the binding `f1 => f1_` wouldn't work. `f1_` is a completely valid function with `class(delegate)`, it just means that the `self` argument is polymorphic (so you could pass any type which extends `delegate` to `self`).

Comment: Thanks. I'm not 100% sure to understand the difference between the solution  the binding `f1 => f1_` and the one without. But this is due to my ignorance. I'll try to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions in order:

- It doesn't look like you've done anything dangerous or wrong. This looks to me like a good use case for procedure pointers, and your implementation looks good.
- The `abstract interface` is basically just defining the "type signature" of the procedure pointer. It doesn't add any overhead.
- You will (unless it's somehow optimised out) have the overhead of a single pointer lookup every time you call `fptr`. This might or might not interfere with some possible compiler optimisations. It's really hard to say whether this will actually meaningfully slow anything down without just trying it to see, and running a code profiler to find out.